# DevExpress EditMask

Tags: c#, regex, devexpress

I'm using a Dev Express `RepositoryItemTextEdit`, and I'm looking to set the Edit Mask to help ensure the users input is in the correct format.

The desired behavior is to get the user enter on or more 6-digit numbers either comma separated or using a hyphen to specify a range.

eg:

```
000002, 000005-000025, 000029-00200, 999999
```

I'm sure I should be able to do this using the MaskType of RegEx, I'm having difficulty coming up with the correct RegEx.

Do any RegEx Experts know how to put that one together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is easy to achieve if you have access to a full POSIX regex engine (for instance if you're using Perl or Python):

```
'\d{6}((,\s|-)\d{6})*$'
```

Accordingly to [this Support Center thread](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q319168) end of string anchors are not supported by DevExpress editors but they are not required so you could try just:

```
'\d{6}((,\s|-)\d{6})*'
```

and see if it works for you (I can't test it myself as I don't use DevExpress editors).